# React Formik Form not calling onSubmit function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap, formik, yup

I have a Formik form, using react-bootstrap for layouts and yup for validation, as follows:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Formik, Field } from "formik";
import * as Yup from 'yup';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';


const VehicleForm2 = ({ action = "create" }) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const VehicleValidationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    vehicleMake: Yup.string()
      .required('Vehicle Make is required'),
    vehicleModel: Yup.string()
      .required('Vehicle Model is required')
 });

const [initialValues, setValues] = useState({
    vehicleMake: "",
    vehicleModel: ""
  });

const { id = "" } = useParams();
  const handleSubmit = async (values) => {
    var receivedData = "";
    console.log("ENTERED SUBMIT METHOD");
    try {
      if (action === "create") {
        await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/vehicle/add`, {
          ...values,
        }).then(function (response) {
          receivedData = response.data.Message;
        });}
      else {
        await axios.patch(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/vehicle/edit/${id}`,
          {
            ...values
          }
        );
      }
      history.push({pathname: '/vehicles',
        state: { message: receivedData }
      });
    } catch (error) { console.log(error)}
  };

 return (
    <Formik       
    initialValues={initialValues}
    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    validationSchema={VehicleValidationSchema}
    render={({handleChange, handleSubmit, handleBlur, values, errors}) => (
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Form.Label>Make</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type="text" name="make" defaultValue={initialValues.make} placeholder="Enter make" />
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <Form.Label>Model</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type="text" name="vehicleModel" defaultValue={initialValues.vehicleModel} placeholder="Enter vehicle model" />
          </Col>
          <Row>
            <Button variant="primary" type="submit" style={{ width: "50%", margin: "auto" }}>
              {action === "create" ? "Create Vehicle" : "Edit Vehicle"}
            </Button>
          </Row>
      </Form>
    )}
/>
```

On loading of the Edit Vehicle form, all fields are populated as expected. However, when I change a field's value and press the Submit button, the handleSubmit function doesn't seem to be entered (because the console log at the top of the handleSubmit() function doesn't print). Instead, the page just reloads and shows the original values, and not the changes.

Also, the validation doesn't kick in when clearing an input and tabbing to the next.

Can you kindly help me identify what I am doing wrong please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the validation is failing because you're looking for `vehicleMake`, instead you're passing `make`.

```
const [initialValues, setValues] = useState({
    vehicleMake: "",
    vehicleModel: ""
  });

<Form.Control type="text" name="make" defaultValue={initialValues.make} placeholder="Enter make" />
```

So i think you need to update `name="vehicleMake"` and `initialValues.vehicleMake`

Comment: I've changed those values but it is still behaving the same way. There are other fields in the form which all have the correct naming too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing `onSubmit` on Form? You only need to add `onSubmit` to `Formik` provider

```
<Formik onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <Form>
  </Form>
</Formik>
```

if the above doesn't work try using the form from `formik`. For example:

```
import Formik, {Form} from "formik"
import BootstrapForm from "react-bootstrap/Form"
...
<Formik onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <Form>
     <Row>
          <Col>
            <BootstrapForm.Label>Make</BootstrapForm.Label>
             ...
          </Col>
     </Row>
  </Form>
</Formik>
```